# Why does rendering add geometry?

Tags: rendering

Why does rendering add like some sort of geometry?

You can see how it is modelled and the material preview on the first picture and then the render is shown on the second picture.

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Ah, clear! I indeed had a cube hidden.
However, I still have this black part on my white drawer as you can see in the picture below. I don't have anything else hidden anymore.

What might that be?

[image]

Comment: Check your outliner. There's a cube you hid in the viewport, but not from rendering.

Comment: Rendering doesn't add geometry. It can only show geometry which is hidden in the viewport. Or in case of e.g. displacement in Cycles it might show geometry different than in solid or material preview mode. But it doesn't geometry that's not already present in some way or another in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Blender gives you a number of options to alter how renders look compared to viewport, e.g. Subdivision Surface modifier allows you to specify different subdivision levels for viewport and render, also adaptive subdivision together with displacement can make a difference in geometry between Eevee preview and Cycles render. There is also "is viewport" input in geometry nodes, and a Python script could affect the scene differently depending on context.

In your case, it seems you've hidden some objects by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> key - this is however a feature to only temporarily hide an object. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> combo in viewport to reveal all hidden objects. If your viewport still displays the scene differently, Enable "Disable in Viewports" icon in your *Outliner* and make sure to set each object's "Disable in Render" setting to be the same:

[image]

The black artifacts are called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) and are caused by two overlapping objects - select one and hide it (but not using the <kbd>H</kbd> key, either delete it permanently or disable it in render).

Comment: I don't have any more hidden objects. I tried enabling "Disable in Viewports" and deleting one of the overlapping objects, but that doesn't make a difference. It is still there.

Comment: @DPlayground maybe it's not another object but e.g. duplicated geometry inside a single Mesh?